# Not able to write to a json file

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to be able to write to a json file. I think maybe I missed something because I'm not able to write to the json file and no errors show up.

Here is my code

```
public function writingToFile($id, $from, $to)
{

    mkdir($this->getStoragePath($id, "/file/$to"));

    foreach(['name', 'area'] as $file){
        copy($this->getStoragePath($id, "/file/$from/$file.json"), $this->getStoragePath($id, "/file/$to/$file.json"));
    }

    $version_file->area = $to;
    $json_file = file_get_contents($this->getStoragePath($id, '/file/$to/area.json'));
    $version_file = json_decode($json_file);


    file_put_contents($this->getStoragePath($id, "/file/$to/area.json"), json_encode($version_file, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));


}
```

Comment: Can you indicate what particularly is failing?  Does it read the file?  Do the files get copied?

Comment: @NigelRen - The files do get copied. They just don't get written to. So I'm thinking maybe it's on this line `file_put_contents($this->getStoragePath($id, "/file/$to/area.json"), json_encode($version_file, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` but I'm not sure

Comment: Always worth trying to split it out for debugging, so check that `$this->getStoragePath()` is giving you what you would expect, and that the `json_encode()` is doing the same.  You can also check the return value from `file_put_contents()` to see what happens there.

Comment: @NigelRen - Thank you so much. If it wasn't for your advice, I think I would have gone mad. The issue was that I needed to put double quotes for `$json_file = file_get_contents($this->getStoragePath($id, '/file/$to/area.json'));` instead of single quotes